# Python v3.9 stopped responding kivy textinput

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I looked up kivy just today and I was just trying the widgets, everything worked fine until I used the TextInput and when I run it shows a black screen then notify me that python v3.9 stopped responding. When I remove the TextInput widget everything works fine again.

**The main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class WidgetsButtonClickExample(GridLayout):
        my_text = StringProperty("0")
        count = 0
        is_on = BooleanProperty(False)
    def on_button_click(self):
        print("Button Clicked")
        if self.is_on:
            self.count += 1
        self.my_text = str(self.count)

    def on_toggle_button_state(self, toggle_button):
        print("Toggle button state: " + toggle_button.state)
        if toggle_button.state == "normal":
            toggle_button.text = "OFF"
            self.is_on = False
        else:
            toggle_button.text = "ON"
            self.is_on = True

    def switch_on_active(self, switch):
        print("Switch: " + str(switch.active))

    def on_slider_value(self, slider):
        print("Slider value: " + str(int(slider.value)))
class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

**The .kv file**

```
WidgetsButtonClickExample:

<WidgetsButtonClickExample>
    cols: 3
    ToggleButton:
        text: "OFF"
        on_state: root.on_toggle_button_state(self)
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: "100dp"
    Button:
        text: "Count"
        on_press: root.on_button_click()
        disabled: not root.is_on
    Label:
        text: root.my_text
        font_name: "fonts/Lcd.ttf"
        font_size: "50dp"
        color: 1, .5, 1, .7
    Switch:
        id: my_switch
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: "100dp"
        on_active: root.switch_on_active(self)
    Slider:
        disabled: not my_switch.active
        id: my_slider
        min: 0
        max: 100
        value: 50 # default value
        # on_value: root.on_slider_value(self)
        orientation: "horizontal" # v/h
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: str(int(my_slider.value))
            # size_hint: 1, 1
        ProgressBar:
            max: 100 # min is always 0
            value: my_slider.value
    TextInput:
```

If I remove the last line of the .kv file everything works as expected. Can anyone help me with this?